# What happened to the mobile view?

Tags: support, bug, design, mobile-web

Previously the mobile view worked fairly well (not the app, the actual mobile site).

At some point in the past few days it appears that the top menu (the inbox header and the Questions/Tags/Users bar) got shrunk significantly. Usernames/posts/comments also are rendering... weirdly.

I'm assuming that given how weird the display looks that it is a bug. You can sort of see the behavior if you go to the mobile full site, but the size differences are much more apparent on a phone vs computer browser.

I am using a Moto G.

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you post a screenshot? This might be something on your side.

Comment: @ShadowWizard was adding it but you apparently saw this question in 3 seconds :)  It's there now.

Comment: Looks like you have a device with wide screen, on my screen (LG G3) [it's looking fine](http://i.stack.imgur.com/n4tqw.png), probably they went with the standard screen size.

Comment: @ShadowWizard my Moto G has... 720x1280 resolution. It's a pretty low resolution smartphone all things considered. Also, if you view the site as mobile on a computer I see similarly out of proportion behavior.

Comment: on computer of course it will look weird. Not sure about mobile resolution, maybe something in your settings.